# Why is my Mamiya-Sekor E f/1.7 lens stuck at f/16 both on and off the camera?

Tags: lens, aperture, troubleshooting, vintage, mamiya

I recently bought a Mamiya ZE Quartz with a Mamiya-Sekor E f/1.7 50mm lens that I recently found at an antique store. It's either been abused or been used a lot, but it's seen better days.

For some reason when I take the lens off and I look through it, its aperture is closed to f/16 even when I move the dial to f/1.7. It also only shoots in f/16 when it's attached to the camera. I read somewhere that the aperture is adjusted electronically because of the metal contacts on the body and on the lens but I'm not really sure since I've never shot with a Mamiya and I haven't tried it with batteries yet.

Help?

Comment: Did you say that the aperture is adjusted electronically, but you haven't used the camera with batteries? If it's controlled electronically, how is it supposed to work without batteries?

Answer (score 2):

The Mamiya ZE is an electronic camera, without batteries it will fall back to a shutter speed of 1/90 s. The aperture should be wide open however, just like any other SLR, for focusing and metering. So the lens is likely defective.